# holomorphic on right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Could any one tell me how to solve this one?

Let $f$ be holomorphic function in the right half plane, with $|f(z)|<1$ for all $z\in \{z:Re(z)>0\}$, $f(1)=0.$ Find out largest possible value of $|f(2)|.$

Comment: @ Taxi Driver: What do you mean the right half plane? Is it open or close one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\phi(z) = \frac{1-z}{1+z}$. $\phi$ is a Möbius transformation that maps $U$, the open unit disk, into the right half plane. Let $\tilde{f} = f \circ \phi$. Then $\tilde{f}$ maps $U$ into itself, and $\tilde{f}(0) = f(1) = 0$. Hence the Schwartz lemma tells us that $|\tilde{f}(z)| \le |z|$ for $z \in U$. We have $\phi(-\frac{1}{3}) = 2$, hence this tells us that $|f(2)| = |\tilde{f}(-\frac{1}{3})| \le \frac{1}{3}$.

If we let $f(z) = \phi(z)$, we get $f(2) = -\frac{1}{3}$, hence the maximum is attained.

Comment: @ copper.hat: How about $f(z):=1-\exp(-10z)?$

Comment: @user64494: $f(1) \neq 0$?

Comment: @ copper.hat: You are right.

Comment: @ copper.hat: Does $\phi(z) := \frac{1-z}{1+z}$ maps the open unit disk into the right half plane?

Comment: @user64494: Yes. It is a Möbius transformation and $\phi(1) = 0$, $\phi(i) = -i$ and $\phi(-1) = \infty$. Hence the unit circle is mapped into the (extended) imaginary axis.

Comment: @ copper.hat: But $1/2\phi(z)$ and $2\phi(z)$ also map the open unit disk onto the open right halfplane.

Comment: @user64494 Yes. So what?

Comment: @Potato: This implies different estimates than $\frac 1 3$, is not so?

Comment: @user64494 Why would it? There are many maps from the half plane to the unit disk. The point of using this one is that it sends $1$ to $0$, so that the corresponding function in the disk vanishes at $0$.

Comment: @Potato: the functions $1/2\phi(z)$ and $2\phi(z)$ also possess this property.

Comment: @user64494: The point is the Schwartz lemma which shows that the values must be $\le \frac{1}{3}$. Since we can exhibit a function that attains this value, we are finished. Unless there is a point that needs clarification, perhaps we could move on?

Comment: @user64494 First, of all, the map $\phi$ in the answer maps the half plane to the disk, not the other way around. Second, you can repeat the argument with $1/2\phi$ (but not $2\phi$, since that no longer maps to $\mathbb D$). You'll get the same answer.

Comment: @ copper.hat: Let us apply the Schwartz lemma with $1/2\phi(z)$ instead of $\phi(z)$. What does it produce?

Comment: @Potato: The function $\phi(z)$ does not map the open right halfplane onto the open unit disk centered at $0$.

Comment: @ copper.hat: I see: $2\phi(0) \neq 1$.

Comment: @user64494: $\phi$ is its own inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Conformally map it into the unit disk. You get a map $\mathbb D\rightarrow \mathbb D$, so the Schwarz lemma applies.

You can also send the image of $1$ in the unit disk to $0$ using a Blaschke factor (if necessary). If, after all of these maps, $2$ is sent to the point $w$, the Schwarz lemma tells you that $|f(w)|\le |w|$. Now just unwrap all of the maps to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map $F:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{H},$ defined by $F(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the right half plane. Note that $F(0)=1$. Now compose $F$ with that of $f$. The map $f\circ F$ is a map from disc to itself which fixes the origin. Use Schwarz Lemma to show that the maximum value is $\frac{1}{3}.$